# How to implement manually a function overloading of adding integers in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, function, integer

I tried a challenge and I can't seem to get it right. I know Python doesn't support function overloading but I have seen some that has done it manually.

I used two arguments to add the 2 numbers and three arguments to add the 3 numbers then used an array with the size of 4 for adding the 4 numbers but I can't seem to get past the sum of the two numbers. I just used my other codes as reference as to how I came up with my code.

```
    def add(a, b):
        sum1 = sum(a,b)
        return sum1

    def add(c,d, e):
        sum2 = sum(c,d,e)
        return sum2

    def add(f,g,h,i):
        sum3 = sum(f,g,h,i)
        return sum3

a,b = int(input("Enter two numbers: ").split())
print("The sum is: ", add(a,b))

c,d,e = int(input("Enter three numbers: ").split())
print("The sum is: ", add(c,d,e))

f,g,h,i  = [int(x) for x in input("Enter four numbers: ").split()]
print("The sum of is: ", add(f,g,h,i))
```

Comment: Check this [blog](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/overload-functions-in-python-13e32ahzqt)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to add numbers in n time in a function then you can do

if we keep 2 nums are minimum no require

```
def add(a, b, *args):
    return a+b+sum(args)
```

or you can use

```
def add(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

now you can add any amount of numbers

in other way

```
def add(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a', 0)
    b = kwargs.get('b', 0)
    return a+b # or sum(kwargs.values())

print(add(a=1, b=2)) 
# if you want another variable in function so you need to write that also
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can put the arguments manually, like I want to show in the code all the variables?

Comment: you can put the arguments in function, but inside the fucntion if you to see arguments you can use print(args) or if you want to use say add function this way `add(a=1,b=2,c=3....) ` ie define the variable name also then use `def add(**kwargs): return sum(kwargs.values())` and if you do `print(kwargs)` you can see all the variable defined there

Comment: `add(a=1,b=2,c=3....)` does this mean that the values of a is 1, b is 2.. etc?